# model_fn() function in R

Tags: r

I follow this **Hands-On Machine Learning with R** book by *Bradley Boehmke & Brandon Greenwell*.

But in this [page](https://bradleyboehmke.github.io/HOML/process.html#prerequisites) I had error, the function `model_fn()` could not be found.

What library I have to include to use the function?

I already included library `tidymodels` but it didn't work.

Comment: There is no function called `model_fn`. It says in the text "_To illustrate, suppose we have some generic modeling function called model_fn() which accepts an R formula, as in the following examples_". You are not supposed to run this code, it is just illustrating how many of the modelling functions in R are called. It is just a pseudo-code showing you how the formula interface for functions work. I'm voting to close this question (not because it is a bad question, but because it is not reproducible as it is based on a simple misunderstanding).

Comment: @AllanCameron: sure but they should have called it `your_fn` to be even more obvious.

Comment: @smci yeah, it's not 100% clear, and I don't blame the OP at all for missing it. In fact, I upvoted because I think it's a useful question.